# mktime VS time PHP4 VS PHP5

Tags: php

I download event calender from http://www.phpcodeworks.com/pec/installation. I am using PHP 5.3.X therefore browser said **F:\xampp\htdocs\msj\functions.php** so I replace :

```
$days = date("t", mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
```

with:

```
$days = date("t",` time(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));
```

but doing so each date goes 24 hours back as follows.

Image when using `$days = date("t", mktime(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));`:

[image]

Image when using `$days = date("t", time(0,0,0,$month,1,$year));`:

[image]

Comment: I've improved your inline and block code formatting (may take a few minutes to be approved) so the question is clearer - but +1 for clear screenshots!

Comment: Check your error reporting is on E_ALL and ensure there are no warnings and notices. Also, this issue might be down to timezones: midnight without a timezone may cross back to the previous day when a timezone is applied.

Comment: As far as I know the `time` function doesnt take any arguments.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [`mktime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) function returns the time in seconds from Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT) to the date and time provided as parameters.

The [`time()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) function retuns the time in seconds from Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT) to the moment the function is run. There are no parameters to pass in.

So when browsing for a particular date, you will need to use `mktime()` instead of `time()`, `time()` will constantly return a different number every time you run it. Because of that, your calendar will change every time you view it (even if you are trying to view a particular date).

**Hightlight:**

`mktime()` - Time in seconds representing a specified date (see the documentation for the required parameters).

`time()` - Time in seconds representing now (there are no parameters for this function).

`mktime()` looks to be the appropriate function for this situation.

Comment: In addition to the answer, `time()` is equivalent to `strotime("now")`